# Are these unique identifiers in the registry? If so, how can I detect them?

Tags: python, windows-10, registry

[image: Screenshot of the registry path]

I'm developing a script that will automatize performance tweaks according to the user's choice when running it.
Then I came accross this path in the registry and I'm wondering how I would possibly find this path automatically considering that it is formed by random strings of numbers and characters.

It seems that these are unique IDs of some sort.
The programming language I'm scripting it is Python 3 and reg.exe is being used along with Popen to strip unecessary bloat from the registry.

Comment: Popen is messy plus it is reinventing the wheel.

Why not use https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winreg.html (chage the url to match your version of Python)?

Are you trying to find all keys that match a prefix?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to find the key after HKEY_USERS and before SOFTWARE. It happens again after Group Policy Objects. I'm wondering what they are and how to find them so I can modify a key. But since it's not a static path, there is no way I can get away with hardcoding it. Thanks for the tip on the winreg.

Comment: Ok, looks like this will require a linear search. Find the most specific static parent key, then iterate all subkeys and hold on to the keys that match a regex. You can find an example here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53858/winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE   Search for `regex`. Takes a little bit of effort to figure this out but it's not too bad.

Comment: Oh this is gonna take some time with python :P. I think I'll simply omit the changing of this value then. I still wonder what those random numbers are.